# Swift 3.0 + iOS 10 + Singleton sharedInstance - Update the UI after data array changes (the Angular Way)

Tags: ios, asynchronous, swift3, singleton, quickblox

Soooo.... I'm a JS dev and I'm building an app in Swift 3.0 for iOS 10+ and I want to interact with data much in the same way I do in Angular 1.6+...

Here is my situation:

I have a Singleton sharedInstance that house session data for a webRTC session. One of the properties of the sharedInstance holds an array of UInt and I need to update a UI element (IBOutlet) to show the user who the available opponents are they can call at any given moment.

In angular I would just update the model and the view/UI would change automatically... boom bang... done...

I am looking to create the same behavior in Swift 3.0 so here goes some code:

```
class Singleton {

    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

    var session = (
        peers: [UInt]()
    )

    private init() { }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var UIPeerList: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIPeerList.text = String(describing: Singleton.sharedInstance.session.peers)
        self.updatePeerList(room: roomName, completion: {(oUser: AnyObject) -> Void in
            QBRequest.dialogs(
                for: QBResponsePage(limit: 100, skip: 0),
                extendedRequest: [roomName : "name"],
                successBlock: {(
                    response: QBResponse,
                    dialogs: [QBChatDialog]?,
                    dialogsUsersIDs: Set<NSNumber>?,
                    page: QBResponsePage?
                ) -> Void in
                    print("<------------------------------<<< Successfully found chat dialog - " + roomName)
                }, errorBlock: { (response: QBResponse) -> Void in
                    print("<------------------------------<<< Handle Error finding chat dialog - " + roomName)
                    let chatDialog: QBChatDialog = QBChatDialog(dialogID: nil, type: QBChatDialogType.group)
                    //chatDialog.occupantIDs = []
                    //chatDialog.occupantIDs?.append(NSNumber(value: DataModel.sharedInstance.qbLoginParams.id))
                    //chatDialog.occupantIDs?.append(12186)
                    chatDialog.setValue(roomName, forKey: "Name")
                    QBRequest.createDialog(chatDialog, successBlock: {(response: QBResponse?, createdDialog: QBChatDialog?) in
                        print("<------------------------------<<< Success creating chat dialog")
                        print(response ?? "No Response")
                        print(createdDialog ?? "No Created Dialog")
                    }, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse!) in
                        print("<------------------------------<<< Error creating chat dialog")
                        print(response ?? "No Response")
                    })
                }
            )
        })
```

So above in the controller I set the UI element to the datasource right after the viewDidLoad is triggered (I know this is not exactly what's going on currently.) Now whenever I change the Singleton.sharedInstance.session.peers data model like for instance here in this ASYNC API request I want the UI to update:

```
func updatePeerList( room: String, completion: @escaping (_ response: AnyObject) -> ()) {
        QBRequest.users(
            withTags: [room],
            page: QBGeneralResponsePage(currentPage: 1, perPage: 10),
            successBlock: {( response: QBResponse, page: QBGeneralResponsePage?, users: [QBUUser]? ) -> Void in
                guard users != nil else { return }
                print("<------------------------------<<< Success getting users with room tag - "+room)
                DataModel.sharedInstance.sessionInfo.peers.removeAll()
                for object in users! {
                    DataModel.sharedInstance.sessionInfo.peers.append(object.id)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(response) }
            }, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse!) in
                print("<------------------------------<<< Error getting users with room tag - "+room)
                print(response)
                DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(response) }
            }
        )
    }
```

> > > > > How do I achieve such a feat?

NOTE: I believe this is possible as I looked into the UISwitch method however that didn't exactly work as I wanted to..

Comment: In Swift, with multithreading, data races and such, there's a similar behavior for "boom bang done", it's "boom bang crash" ;)   So, what I want to say is, ensure proper synchronisation where you access "shared" variables.

Comment: ain't that the truth lol

Answer (score 1):

One solution that came to my mind is using delegation. There may be more elegant solutions though.

To use delegation, you could go through the following steps:

1- Create a protocol that have one method `update()`, and let's name that protocol `UpdateUIDelegate`.

2- Make your `ViewController` implement that protocol, and implement `update()` method in the way you want.

3- Set your `ViewController` object as a property in the `Singleton` class.

4- Make all changes that affect `Singleton.sharedInstance.session.peers` happen through a method inside `Singleton`, and make that method calls your delegate's update method in its end.

Comment: Hrrmmm... Sounds solid... Mind sharing some code with that tasty morsel of knowledge you just dropped on us? Feel free to chop up what I have above.